# How likely is it for Chang'e 5 to wake up after lunar night?

Tags: the-moon, probe, lunar-landing, chang-e

I have been wondering how likely it would be for the Chang'e 5 Probe to wake up. I mean the surveyors did this a few times, but were all relatively simpler in design.

Also what gets damaged in the lunar night exactly? I would guess the battery but can think of more systems that might die...

Comment: If Chang'e 4 and Yutu 2 are any indication, extremely good! They've been operating for nearly two years now. I don't know the status today but they were still going strong in October: [China's Chang'e-4 probe resumes work for 23rd lunar day](https://www.moondaily.com/reports/Chinas_Change_4_probe_resumes_work_for_23rd_lunar_day_999.html) (lunar day on the moon is lunar month down here)

Comment: @uhoh Ehm. don't forget Chang'e 4 and Yutu 2 are made to survive the lunar night because they have Radioactive Heaters that keep them warm. Chang'e 5 does not have Heaters.

Comment: That's why it begins with "If..." and why it is left as a *comment*.